# How to setup my remote slave with Jenkins?

Tags: ios, xcode, hudson, jenkins

In therory Master is : Job and Slave is : Node (however that what im understand).

I installed JENKINS in 2 machines MAC OS X (maybe windows whatever), I set up my job with a correct repository and configure xCode in this job etc ... like same tutorial, i set up my slave etc ... all fine and 10/10 BUTTT this test is local test, in one machine.

My problem is : I want have SLave(Node) for building my xCode Project in MAC OS, and My Matser (job) in others server (why not my seconde machine MAC OS X), How i can establish connection between slave (Node) and Master(job) for building my project xCode in my Remote SLave.

Answer (score 1):

Set your job to use "Restrict where this project can be run" by checking the box and put the name of the slave in the box (use quotes if there are spaces

I had a little trouble deciphering your questions so if this does not answer please rework what you are asking.

Comment: i want install my job (Master) in serveur Windows and my slave (node) in MAC OS X for build my project iOS, this is my question

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you are asking now.  Click "manage jenkins" on the left after you log in (On your Master, NOT the mac).  Next, go to "manage nodes".  This is your node list.  Click "new node" on the left. Name it and click "dumb slave".  Click ok, this should take you to the main config page.  For our xCode machine we use the "Java web start" for our "Launch method" option.  Don't forget to set your root and tool locations and such.  Hope this answers your questions

Comment: thx but that not what i want know. Look, i have my job in my mac os, and i want build my project iOS from another mac os, i dont know how a establish connection between machines !!!! i want know if its necessery to install jenkins and configure slave on the machine wish build my project or not !! or in my machines who has job !!

Comment: Ok, sorry I am having trouble understanding.  I think what you want is to install jenkins slaves on both of the mac os.  Then create a project for each one to do the main job and one to do the iOS part.  To link them call the one job from the other via the "Downstream" option.  See these sites to help   
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin  
AND  
https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/477213-doing-choreography-workflow-with-jenkins-cli

Answer (score 1):

Easy set the IP address of the slave host machine in the Jenkins setup. Choose ssh as the communications method and set up accounting information on the slave machines jenkins setup. Make sure the slave machine can ssh to the account and machine you set up in jenkins. Your ready to roll

Answer (score 0):

How to link jobs in Jenkins

**Master** job: **"Trigger/call builds on other projects"**

**Slave** job: Add a Condition Step build: **"Run? Build Cause --> UpstreamCause (with The master project name)"** and then copy the artifacts (*.*) from the "Master" job.

Don't forget to copy from the workspace and not from the latest successful build, since the master didn't finished yet and din't publish the artifacts.